# Remove framerate/duration metadata from h264 with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need a H264 encoded video without framerate and duration metadata as these are stored and calculated externally.

This is what I use:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f image2 -i xyz -c:v libx264 -f h264 1579516080101.h264
```

This is what mediainfo returns:

```
General
Complete name                            : 1579516080101.h264
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
File size                                : 866 KiB
Duration                                 : 1 s 0 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 7 096 kb/s

Video
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Duration                                 : 1 s 0 ms
Bit rate                                 : 7 096 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.114
Stream size                              : 866 KiB (100%)
```

How can I get rid of these entries? I have tried `-map_metadata -1` and setting no framerate, but that just resulted in using a default framrerate of 25.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you really want to achieve here? You're providing a frame rate of 30. Why do you want to remove that? Frame rate is not metadata.

Comment: I have exact timestamps for all of my frames. These timestamps are stored and read externally. I want to keep the videos in lengths of 1s. The frame rate of these videos is not always exactly 30, therefore I would like to remove this information (along with duration). I believe this information is stored in VUI parameters, but I don't know how I can force ffmpeg to stop writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem by modifying the ffmpeg source code and recompiling it.

The relevant bit that needs to be commented out lies in: `FFmpeg/libavcodec/h264_metadata_bsf.c` line 171 onwards:

```
if (ctx->tick_rate.num && ctx->tick_rate.den) {
    int num, den;

    av_reduce(&num, &den, ctx->tick_rate.num, ctx->tick_rate.den,
              UINT32_MAX > INT_MAX ? UINT32_MAX : INT_MAX);

    sps->vui.time_scale        = num;
    sps->vui.num_units_in_tick = den;

    sps->vui.timing_info_present_flag = 1;
    need_vui = 1;
}
```